# Cache list comprehension and processing results

Tags: python, caching

I have a list comprehension, which is created from a dictionary (about 1000 key-value pairs):

```
comprehension_result = [SomeObject(property_a=key, property_b=value) for key, value in some_dictionary.items()]
```

Then I have a list processing method `processing_method`, which iterates over the items in `comprehension_result`, performs some processing, and returns another list:

```
another_list = processing_method(comprehension_result)
```

The result of `another_list` is used in a class property, like:

```
# SomeClass.py

class SomeClass:
    ...
    some_property = another_list
```

The thing is, `SomeClass` can be instantiated many times at once, and the value of `another_list` is obtained on-the-fly, meaning that it is time consuming to create many instances of `SomeClass`.

I want to ask, is there a caching mechanism, or helper function in Python, which can store the value of `another_list` somewhere, so it is only calculated once, and all the instances can use that?

Comment: `some_property` is a class variable so it's shared between all instances of `SomeClass` already. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: In your sample code, `another_list` is a global variable and all instances of `SomeClass` will refer to it indirectly through `some_property` which is a _class_ attribute, not an instance attribute.